# Converting .ps file to .jpg file

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I tried to convert .ps file which replace in my home directory using

```
convert intensity.ps intensity,jpg
```

but i got some error

Error: /undefined in Standard+_Encoding
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2045   1   3   %oparray_pop   2044   1   3   %oparray_pop   2025   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
--dict:962/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--   --dict:117/250(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 1184658
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Error: /undefined in Standard+_Encoding
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2045   1   3   %oparray_pop   2044   1   3   %oparray_pop   2025   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
--dict:962/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--   --dict:117/250(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 1184658
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
convert: no images defined `intensity.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.

i tried to change permisions in /etc/Imagemagick-6/policy.xml and it didn't work too

Comment: Standard+_Encoding isn't the 'usual' name, it should be StandardEncoding. Most likely your PostScript file is broken, but.. You are using an old version of Ghostscript, you should try the current version (10.01.2). If the problem persists then you should open a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com. It isn't possible to say any more without looking into the PostScript program.

Comment: Ghostscript 9.26 is known to have errors. Please upgrade to the latest Ghostscript.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.